# Auto-hide MenuStrip like Windows Explorer menu bar

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to emulate the behavior of Windows explorer menu bar (win7).

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37579022/4934172) and it does NOT meet my requirements.

**Expected behavior:**

- Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> key ==> toggle `visible` property of the `MenuStrip`.
- Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+`access key char` ==> show the `MenuStrip` and open the targeted menu.
- Interact with any other area of the form (i.e. deactivate `MenuStrip`) ==> Hide `MenuStrip`.

**My "*minimal, complete, and verifiable*" code:**

```vb
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.KeyPreview = True
    menuBar.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub frmMain_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Menu Then ' Requirement #1
        menuBar.Visible = Not menuBar.Visible
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub frmMain_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.Alt AndAlso e.KeyCode <> Keys.Menu Then ' Requirement #2
        menuBar.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub menuBar_MenuDeactivate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles menuBar.MenuDeactivate
    menuBar.Visible = False ' Requirement #3
End Sub
```

**The problem:**

When pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key while the `MenuStrip` is visible, the event `MenuDeactivate` is triggered and the `MenuStrip` becomes hidden on `KeyDown`, then becomes shown again on `KeyUp`.

I tried adding a boolean, set it to false in `KeyDown` event then set it to true in `KeyUp` event, so I can check its value before setting `menuBar.Visible = False` but, unexpectedly the event `MenuDeactivate` fires before `KeyDown` whether the `keydown` event is for the form or the menustrip.

Any Ideas?

**Side note**: Although my code is in VB, any answer with C# code is welcomed.

Comment: To see a working example which supports both mouse and keyboard activation, take a look at: [Auto-hide menu in Windows Forms](http://www.reza-aghaei.com/auto-hide-menu-in-windows-forms/). Also when showing by alt key, it's better to activate the menu as well, then users can use navigation keys also to navigate between menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure out a workaround for this problem, which is to simply check if the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is pressed/held down before hiding the `MenuStrip` in the `MenuDeactivate` event, like this:

```vb
If Not My.Computer.Keyboard.AltKeyDown Then menuBar.Visible = False
```

**The complete implementation** *in case someone is interested*:

```vb
Private Sub frmMain_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Menu Then
        menuBar.Visible = Not menuBar.Visible
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub frmMain_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.Alt AndAlso e.KeyCode <> Keys.Menu Then
        menuBar.Visible = True
    ElseIf e.KeyData = Keys.Escape Then
        menuBar.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub menuBar_MenuDeactivate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles menuBar.MenuDeactivate
    If Not My.Computer.Keyboard.AltKeyDown Then menuBar.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Hope it will help someone :)