# Autohide MenuStrip - How to activate it when showing?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, menustrip

I have a `MenuStrip` and I make it `AutoHide` using following code. It hides/shows prefect but when a control get focus, by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, `MenuStrip` shows but it is not active and there is not small underline under shortcut keys for example under 'F' for File , and pressing 'F' will not open it). How can I correctly active it?

Note: I used `MenuDeactivate` instead of it but it did not work prefect.

```
bool menuBarIsHide = true;
bool altKeyIsDown = false;
bool alwaysShowMenuBar=false;
//KeyPreview is true;
//for prevent glitch(open/close rapidly)
void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Alt) != 0)
        altKeyIsDown = false;
}
void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Alt) != 0)
    {
        if (altKeyIsDown)
            return;
        if (!alwaysShowMenuBar)
        {
            if (menuBarIsHide)
            {
                menuBar.Show();
                menuBarIsHide = false;
                //manage container height
            }
            else
            {
                menuBar.Hide();
                menuBarIsHide = true;
                //manage container height
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To see a working example which supports both mouse and keyboard activation, take a look at: [Auto-hide menu in Windows Forms](http://www.reza-aghaei.com/auto-hide-menu-in-windows-forms/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override [`ProcessCmdKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) to handle <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to toggle the menu visibility. Also to activate menu, call internal `OnMenuKey` method of `MenuStrip`. Also handle [`MenuDeactivate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.menustrip.menudeactivate?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) to make the menu invisible after finishing your work with menu, but you need to make the menu invisible using [`BeginInvoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8).

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.Alt | Keys.Menu))
    {
        if (!this.menuStrip1.Visible)
        {
            this.menuStrip1.Visible = true;
            var OnMenuKey = menuStrip1.GetType().GetMethod("OnMenuKey", 
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
            OnMenuKey.Invoke(this.menuStrip1, null);
        }
        else
        {
            this.menuStrip1.Visible = false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
private void menuStrip1_MenuDeactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { this.menuStrip1.Visible = false; }));
}
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about applying the solution. Keep in mind you should set `Visible` Property of your `MenuStrip` to `false` at start.  This is the most stable auto hide menu which I know.

Comment: thanks for your response, but there is a problem. if user kept `Alt` key down `menuStrip` will open and close rapidly. how should I fix this problem?

Comment: You're welcome @NokhodSiah it's the default behavior when handling key event. I'll check it and I'll share a solution if I had any :)